# Can we set the java process locale (-Djava.util.locale=es_ES) for java process without restarting the java process

Tags: internationalization

I need to support internationalization , therefore user will select the different langauges that has to be apply to server process and os. we are using CentOS

Can we set the java locale without restarting the java process?
Kindly provide the setups.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support Internationalization, you should not assign Locale at JVM level. Thus, you should not use `-Duser.language` nor `-Duser.country`. You should not also assign locale in the code using `Locale.setDefault()` - this will also set the JVM-wide Locale (which will affect ***all*** running Java applications).

It is not clear, what you are after, but personally I sense some misconception in your question.

If you want to support I18n, what you need to do is to *detect* Locale and optionally track them. Depending on the type of application and environment, it might be quite simple (`Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)` in desktop applications (***only***)) or quite complex (reading Locale from request context and storing it as a session variable in case of web applications).
As you can see, there is no need to assign default Locale and it should be left to JVM start-up code.

Comment: As we are working on Appliance , User will select the locale to update to Appliance/server with our application. based on that we are updating the centos i18n file for locale and updating the vm argument. and restarting the complete appliance to reinitiaze the os , java, webapps, db, rabbitmq with new locale. in that case -Djava.util.locale is the only option. Do we have any other way to do that ?

Comment: @piyush: Since you need to restart the whole stack, I don't think there is any way to get around this (after all you probably need to reread language-dependent data, for example from database). I don't think that dynamically changing VM parameter would resolve anything. What you can do is to set default locale at runtime (with `Locale.setDefault()`), but you will still need to reinitialize all the components somehow. So I don't think it will be easy to avoid the downtime.

Comment: @piyush: The only other option that I can think of would be to make the whole stack language-agnostic, that is to avoid dependency on Locale. If you come to think about it, the only place where you really need a Locale is User Interface, and in terms of Appliance Business that usually means some web application. So if you can actually store language-independent data in the whole thing and resolve strings at display time, you may avoid both downtimes and the need to ever switch Locale. But I believe that at this stage it would mean a lot of work and money (this is architecture level bug).

Comment: Thanks for input. we have just started the application , its not legacy app. we are trying to control app server, / third party lib from centralize file i18n (has locale info), where we update the locale when user modifies from the web pages. it means only option is to provide the vm argument language/country and init the vm with that locale. i was just figuring out whether its possible to reinit the java process without restarting with new locale and will take care while restart also.